# Flickering lines on wayland with fracktional scaling 125%

Tags: wayland, scaling

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 w/ Wayland because of the better implementation of fractional scaling. I'm using a WQHD monitor so it's quite small in 100% mode.

**From time to time**, I notice flickering lines (horizontal and vertical), in different programs. This happens every two or three days.

For example in `qterminal`, when installing a snap

```
snap install signal-desktop
```

there is a rotating / at the right side. There are flickering lines above and below this terminal line. But the flickering happens in all programms, firefox, thunderbird, ...

Something in the rendering seems to be broken.

When I switch to 100% and then back to 125%, the issue is solved but it's really annoying.

Anyone knows what's causing this and how to really fix it?

Comment: I was in a similar situation and after reading your question I turned off Wayland and removed the fractional scaling. I haven't had anymore flickering so far. Fingers crossed.

Comment: To be honest, I stopped using Wayland. It's buggy like crap. These flickering lines are so annoying and some applications (Java?) have incredible small and overlapping fonts. Plus, some apps like Shutter do not work on wayland.